# Does AsyncTask really do things in background?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I used AsyncTask to get html files from server. But when an activity starts, screen becomes white few seconds and displays data when fully downloaded.

I wanted it to display activity's basic layout first(e.g. actionbar) and downloaded data later. So I used `Thread` and the problem solved.(basic layout is first shown and data later)

I've been knowing `AsyncTask` do things asynchronously but in my case it didn't.(In `doInBackground`, I only did network connection)

Does AsyncTask really do things in background?

Comment: Please post your code where you attempted to use AsyncTask.  If implemented correctly, it should run in a separate background thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does AsyncTask really do things background?

Yes.

Note, though, that `AsyncTask` is serialized by default, meaning that if you fork multiple `AsyncTask` instances, they will share a single thread, and the second and subsequent tasks will be queued up waiting until the first task completes. You can avoid this via using `executeOnExecutor()`, instead of `execute()`, to run the tasks.

There are other ways of misusing `AsyncTask` (e.g., calling `get()`) as well.

Comment: I used `get()` to return data from `doInBackground()` Is it wrong? What method should I use?

Comment: @user3858358: "Is it wrong?" -- yes, as that will block until `doInBackground()` completes. "What method should I use?" -- you override `onPostExecute()` in your `AsyncTask` subclass. You do your work that needs the results from `doInBackground()` in `onPostExecute()`.